word macro vba to replace symbols
I have a document of nealry 600 pages with hundreds of dialogues starting with "«" symbol and ending with "»" symbol.
My problem is that all of the dialogues ends ".»" but they should end without the ".".
To be clear, instead of having "«xxx.»", I must have "«xxx»".
The normal substitue function is not working as well as the macros I tried.
Is there a way to achieve my goal with a macro as to avoid to do it manually?
Thanks to everyone.
I tried to substitue the string with a find & replace:
.text = "." & "chrw(187)
.replacement.text = chrw(187)
but the macro gives as replacement text a " instead of a ».

Getting " instead of >> maybe down to the choice of font selected.

I guess this something related with the character codes in VBA Find/Replace box that it does not recognize the "»" character well.
I have made a test using a simple UserForm and simulate the Find/Replace dialog which ended with success.
I prepared a simple UserForm with a textbox and a commandbutton.
In the UserForm module, I have the following code;
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim regExp As Object
    
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    
    regExp.Pattern = "\." & TextBox1.Text
    regExp.Global = True
    regExp.MultiLine = True
    
    ActiveDocument.Range.Text = regExp.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range.Text, TextBox1.Text)
    Unload Me
    
    Set regExp = Nothing
End Sub

Before running the UserForm, copy the » character from the document. Then, run the UserForm and paste into the TextBox, then hit the CommandButton to run the code.

It should change all the ".»" strings to "»" if nothing goes wrong.

The real problem is probably not in the way you are doing the Replace. It's in the Word "Auto Format As You Type" settings.
In VBA,
Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False

( or just
Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False

)
and of course you might need to save the value and restore it after the Replace operation.
Manually in Word, it is something like this: (right now I'm using a rather old version so yours may be different, even in the English language version):
Uncheck Word->Options->Proofing->AutoCorrect Options->AutoFormat As You Type->Replace As You Type->"Straight quotes" with "smart quotes".
As far as I can tell, you do not need to uncheck the equivalent Word->Options->Proofing->AutoCorrect Options->AutoFormat->Replace->"Straight quotes" with "smart quotes" . The VBA equivalent of that is
Application.Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False

or just
Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False

)
I would guess that in the majority of cases, having Replace behave as if you're typing is probably what users expect. I do not know how well that works for users whose "smart quotes" are the double chevron characters (e.g. in French language texts AIUI).
Arguably it should be possible to specify, somehow, in the Replace box that you do not want that, but I do not think that is possible.
